# Animacion XML fragment con setTransition no funciona

Tags: android, android-studio, xml, android-fragment

ya llevo tiempo programando con Android Studio no me gusta utilizar mucho XML por eso las Animaciones por lo general las creo en java pero lo que me di cuenta es que con el `FragmentManager` no hay un metodo para colocarla toca por XML con el `setTransition` asi:

**MainActivity.java**

```
FragmentManager FM=getSupportFragmentManager();
FM.beginTransaction().setTransition(R.anim.fadein).replace(R.id.root,new BlankFragment()).commit();
```

**fadein.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="5000" />
</set>
```

Me podrian por favor decir que tengo mal; revisando detalladamente el LogCat no lanza nada

Comment: ¿has revisado que se muestra en el LogCat?

Comment: @Jorgesys ya coloque lo que me sale en el Log

Comment: @Jorgesys pero no me sale siempre aveces no sale nada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola según la documentación el método **setTransaction** es para signar un efecto estándar al fragment, si quieres asignar tu propia animación debes usar **setCustomAnimations**

Deberías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    transaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left,android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
    transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment);
    transaction.disallowAddToBackStack();

    transaction.commit();
```

En ese ejemplo yo uso unas que ya están el sistema, también puedes agregar una animación por default en el FrameLayout de la siguiente manera:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_above="@+id/navigation"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
</FrameLayout>
```

Este si manejas tus fragments de esa manera.

Si quieres usar una animación por defecto entonces usas el método setTransaction

Ejemplo

```
transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
```